# What is the difference between LCG and Affine cipher?

Tags: algorithm-design, substitution-cipher

What is the difference between LCG and Affine cipher?

More specific: What are they used for, and what are the structural differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

A LCG -- linear congruential generator -- is used to generate a sequence of pseudorandom numbers. Therefore, it takes the previous output to calculate a new number:

y<sub>i</sub> = (a*y<sub>i-1</sub>+c) mod N

With an Affine cipher, in contrast, you can encrypt and decrypt. You can convert your text to a number; for example, character for character "A"->0 "B"->1... "Z"-> 25

To encrypt a message m you use the following formula:

c = (a*m + b) mod N